# CSS Rotate in Not Working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I have a custom Wordpress theme that displays the post's date vertically, to the left of the post:

[image: The Correct Version]

This is the CSS code I used to achieve it:

```
.datebox {
background-color: #371f13;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
z-index: 10;
text-align: center;
left: 280px;
top: 25px;
/* Safari */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 /* Firefox */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* IE */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 /* Internet Explorer */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

}

In IE8 (as rendered by IE 10's debug console), the box does not rotate properly:

[image: IE8 Rendering]

The client is reporting that the date is actually completely upside down (I'm assuming she's using IE8, but I don't yet know for sure).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Comment: No, and it's maddening that you can't have two different versions. I work on a Mac, but I have a PC laptop running Windows 8, and Parallels running Windows 7 and Windows XP. I use the XP to test IE7 (although I'm moving away from that), and Win7 to test IE9. IE8 just sort of fell through the cracks there, and I'm not buying Vista.

Comment: I also have IETester, but that's unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The client reported using IE9, and it turned out that her IE9 (probably running in compatibility mode) was rendering both the CSS and the MS Filter.

I moved the MS-Filter to an IE8-specific stylesheet, and that solved both problems. I did, however, have to adjust the top and left settings in the IE8 version, for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

CSS transforms only work in IE9 and later: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: This is the part of the code that isn't working properly: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);